# What is the difference between 石{いし}、岩{いわ} and 岩石{がんせき}?

Tags: word-choice, wago-and-kango

I'm just a beginner. I think all of them meaning the same, rock. Can anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- 石【いし】: stone, typically of a few centimeters in size
- 岩【いわ】: rock, typically of a few meters or more in size
- 岩石【がんせき】: stones and rocks.

Another important difference is that, as a [Sino-Japanese word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Japanese_vocabulary), 岩石 sounds technical, and used as an academic term for [rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_(geology)) in general. In everyday conversations, 石 and 岩 are commonly used.

Answer (score 13):

According to Japanese dictionary, although it is written about various things in detail, I have an image like an attached file.
In short, "石" is small, 岩 and 岩石 are big.

Hope it helps.
[image]